# In Rails, Can we auto submit data to the controller upon user visit and reload the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Here's what I need to achieve :

A user visit the login page. Upon the first visit, the browser will record his IP and data from a cookie (cookies[:user]) and send it to the server. The server then check whether the IP or the user is in the block list and if the user is in the block list, it will automatically redirect the use to a blocked page!

Can we do this in Rails and how?

Comment: I am sure this is possible, Devise records the user's IP upon login so maybe you could derive it from their implementation. Or if you are using devise, override their sessions controller then do the redirect their after checking the session[:current_sign_in_ip].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done quite easily, take this for example

```
def new
    if cookies[:userid].present?
        if User.find(cookies[:userid]).userblocked == true
            redirect_to "/block_page"
        end
    elsif @failedtries == max_tries
        User.find(cookies[:userid]).userblocked = true
        cookies[:userid] = @id_entered
    end
end
```

Where 'userblocked' is a true or false value in your database. This method is full proof against people who can freely change their IP. However if your heart is set on using IP's then this is an example:

```
def new
    if cookies[:blocked].present?
        redirect_to "/block_page"
    else
        if BlockedIps.find_by_ip(request.remote_ip).blocked == true
            redirect_to "/block_page"
        elsif @failedtries == max_tries
            BlockedIps.find_by_ip(request.remote_ip).blocked = true
            cookies[:blocked] = true
        end
    end
end
```

Something like this could be what you are after. Give it a try, I haven't tested the code. This is just from my head at this moment in time, but it should do what you want, providing you have some sort of system to store the IP in a database when the max tries have reached.

Explanation:
The way it works is that it checks to see if the blocked cookie is present, if so it redirects to the block page, if not it checks to see if the users IP address is in the block list of IP's. If the IP is present and the block column is set to true then the user will be redirected to the block page, else the system checks how many tries they have made and if it is equal to the max tries it adds the users IP to the database and creates a cookie on their PC which can be checked on next visit.

Comment: Perfect. But will it read the cookie before rendering the view?

Comment: Everything that happens in the controller happens before the view is rendered yes. The idea is that you use the controller to do all of your underlying logic and the view is used to display the data from the controller. That's the whole concept behind MVC, is that it separates all the areas, so they have a dedicated purpose, makes for more readability. This probably isn't the best way to do it, but it's the most natural way I could think of at the that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method for checking the IP address and authenticating then use before_action :yourmethod on top of your controllers. before_action runs before any other action in your controller so it is a good way to authenticate before showing any views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conner Stephen McCabe solution above or take a gem for this purpose.
User can easily clear the cookie, so it's not safe anyway.

Example: https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack

Comment: A user can clear a cookie yes, but they can't clear their IP from a database.

Comment: Yes, I've said that your solution is good enough to be quick and working. This is merely an 'alternative'. In simple way we can check this without cookies by: request.remote_ip

Comment: I know, but you stated that it's not safe, and I'm adhering to that, unless you meant using solely a cookie is not safe, then yes I would agree.